# Attempting to bind Guzzle Curl Client to Laravel's Service Container -- then Type Hint the Client Fails when attempting to __construct()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container, type-hinting

So I figured I'd try to actually use this fancy IoC container in Laravel. I'm starting with Guzzle but I cannot get it to work. Perhaps there is a gap in my understanding. I really appreciate any help here.

so I've got a class for connecting to a RESTful Api. Here is a sample from it:

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;

class EtApi {
    //you can pass in the model if you wanna
    //protected $model;

    //client Id
    protected $clientId;

    //client secret
    protected $clientSecret;

    //base_uri
    protected $getTokenUri;

    protected $client;

    //build
    function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->clientId = 's0m3R4nd0mStr1nG';
        $this->clientSecret = 's0m3R4nd0mStr1nG';
        $this->getTokenUri = 'https://rest.api/requestToken';
        $this->accessToken = $this->getToken($this->clientId, $this->clientSecret, $this->getTokenUri);
    }
```

}

I've successfully installed and used Guzzle by manually newing it up inside of methods like $client = new Client(); but that's not very DRY and it's not the right way of doing things. So I created a ServiceProvider at app\Providers\GuzzleProvider.php. I made sure this was registered in app/config/app.php under `$providers = ['App\Providers\GuzzleProvider']`. Here is the Provider Code:

```
    <?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;

class GuzzleProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->app->bind('Client', function () {
            return new Client;
        });
    }

}
```

So when I try to access my EtApi methods that load fails during the instantiation (__construct) with the following error.

```
ErrorException in EtApi.php line 23:
Argument 1 passed to App\EtApi::__construct() must be an instance of GuzzleHttp\Client, none given, called in /home/vagrant/webdocs/et_restful_test/app/Http/Controllers/EtConnectController.php on line 23 and defined
```

Do any of you Laravel Masters have any idea why I can't bind Guzzle using this code and Laravel's magic will just inject the obj into the constructor? The [docs[1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container) say I should be able to do this. I must be missing something. Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little hard to say for certain based on the information in your question, but based on this

> Argument 1 passed to App\EtApi::__construct() must be an instance of GuzzleHttp\Client, none given, called in /home/vagrant/webdocs/et_restful_test/app/Http/Controllers/EtConnectController.php on line 23 and defined

It sounds like you're directly instantiating your `App\Eti` class on line 23 of `EtConnectController.php` with code that looks something like this

```
$api = new App\EtApi;
```

If that's the case, there's a key piece of Laravel's dependency injection you're missing.  Laravel can't change the behavior of standard PHP -- i.e. if you create a new class with PHP's built-in `new` keyword, then Laravel never has the change to inject any dependencies in `__construct`.

If you want to take advantage of dependency injection, you also need to **instantiate your object via Laravel's app container**.  There's many different way to do that -- here's two them

```
//$api = new App\EtApi;
\App::make('App\EtApi');     //probably "the right" way
$api   = app()['App\EtApi']
```

If you do that, Laravel will read the type hints in `__construct` and try to inject dependencies for your object.

Comment: Brilliant! You win Alan Storm. I had defined this method in the controller: `public function etConnect()
    {
        return new EtApi;
    }`       switching that out for `public function etConnect() { return app()['App\EtApi']; }`  solved it.

Comment: @funkenstein You can also use `\App::make('App\EtApi');`. It does the same thing, just depends on style preference. Also, as the way it is written, your Guzzle service provider is not needed at all. Laravel is smart enough to "new up" plain concrete instances without help. If you needed extra functionality for creating the new Guzzle instance, you would use the service provider, but as it is right now, it is not needed at all.

Comment: @patricus is spot on with App::make -- that's "the right" way to do things.  I'm up to elbows in object containers these days and brain farted the `App` facade.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your register function to

```
/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
    $this->app->bind('GuzzleHttp\Client\Client', function () {
        return new Client;
    });
}
```

That should do the trick => the IOC resolves the fqcn and not the short one, so exposing it in your container you'll need to bind it to the fqcn too!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi I tried this and unfortunately still get the same error. `/**
  * Register the application services.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function register()
 {
  //
        $this->app->bind('GuzzleHttp\Client\Client', function () {
            return new Client;
        });
 }`